# When I move a JSF bean from WAR module to a Java library (JAR), the @EJB doesn't works

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, netbeans

I have a JSF bean in WAR module which has an @EJB that works. When I move the JSF bean to a Java library (JAR), the @EJB doesn't works (I get a NullPointerException when I try to access the EJB). I need to move from scenario I to scenario II:

**Scenario I:**

Enterprise Application

WAR Module:

JSF Page:

```
<p>#{testController.test}</p>
```

JSF Bean:

```
@Named
public class TestController {

    @EJB
    private TestEjb testEjb;

    public String getTest() {
        return testEjb.test();
    }

}
```

EJB Module:

```
@Stateless
public class TestEjbImpl implements TestEjb {

    @Override
    public String test() {
        return (new Date()).toString();
    }

}
```

**Scenario II:**

Enterprise Application

WAR Module:

JSF Page:

```
<p>#{testController.test}</p>
```

JSF Bean:

[Empty - the JSF bean was moved to a Java Library (JAR)]

EJB Module:

```
@Stateless
public class TestEjbImpl implements TestEjb {

    @Override
    public String test() {
        return (new Date()).toString();
    }

}
```

Java Library (JAR):

```
@Named
public class TestController {

    @EJB
    private TestEjb testEjb;

    public String getTest() {
        return testEjb.test(); // Here I get a NullPointerException
    }

}
```

I have created an Enterprise Application Project with a Java Library that reproduces this problem. This is a Netbeans Project: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/64616807/stackoverflow/jee6.rar

Comment: Where are you placing the JAR? Is it in `WEB-INF/lib`?

Comment: The Netbeans puts the JAR in lib folder of EAR. There are not WEB-INF/lib folder in EAR/WAR/WEB-INF. I have added the JAR in WAR project (Project Properties | Libraries).